# React Native - Navigation between different views

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, flux

I just approached to react native/react and are a bit confused...I specify that I have a background with angularjs, cordova, ect...Now I have a problem...I'm reading Flux and I want to use it in my application because it improve the structure with the unidirectional data flow.

The most important decision is the navigation in my app, so in the documentation of native react I found the component "Navigator". Now I don't understand if I can use the Navigator and Flux together or one excludes the other.

if you have informations, advices or examples, it's welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Infact you can use combination of both. Here is one library that and provides a router API on top of Navigator.  https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux

Comment: ok...I saw this one on github but I do not want to use and tie me to library written by any person...I want to use Flux and Navigator together in standard mode following the guidelines if it's possible...Do you have an examples or advices? Thanks!

Comment: It could be something like this, whenever you would want to navigate to a different screen, send an action with payload, Use the payload and navigate to specific page using navigator. You could maintain current screen or list of screens in your store.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Unfortubately, I don't have any, but I think the links mentioned in the other answer might help

Answer (score 0):

You can use RN Navigator and Flux together, they're not excluding each other. Here is few navigation articles, that might help you:

- http://blog.paracode.com/2016/01/05/routing-and-navigation-in-react-native/
- http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2015/09/21/react-native-example-app/
- https://medium.com/the-exponent-log/routing-and-navigation-in-react-native-6b27bee39603#.ae10t4lks

You can find they're all stating that you can use Flux actions to dispatch events, update navigation bar buttons and screens content etc.

I'm not using Flux, but on your place I would try to read react-native-router-flux code, read articles and try to buid flux-navigator myself with all that aknowledged ^^. Good luck, I hope this will help you :)